How to check api connection in post method in Xamarin Forms App?
I'm developing an xamarin forms app and I use our api. I need to check "HttpResponseMessage". I can check this in "get" methods but I can't figure it out in "post" method.
How can I check this response inside post method ?
Edit: Problem fixed with a different way.
Actual post method added below code.
Actual Post Method :
 public async Task<Model.Result> PostStokHareketiKaydet(MikroRoot m)
    {
        try
        {
            // http clien oluşturma
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };

            var myValue = Preferences.Get("myServiceIP", "");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://" + myValue);
            string cevap = "";
            //Client Adres
            string url = $"http://" + myValue + "/MikroAPIStokHareketiKaydet";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);
            //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listofProjes).ToString()

            Console.WriteLine("STOK HAREKET JSON :" + json);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            // Post methodu 


            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/MikroAPIStokHareketiKaydet", content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {

                    string adres = $"/MikroAPIStokHareketiKaydet";
                    var postData = await client.PostAsync(adres, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    //Posttan gelen cevabı oluşturma
                    var result = await postData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Result>(result);

                }
                else
                {

                    //Show alert for failed calls

                    Model.Result nullResult = new Model.Result { ResultCode = 200, ResultData = "", ResultFlag = false, ResultValue = "Bağlantı Kesildi." };
                    return nullResult;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Model.Result nullResult = new Model.Result { ResultCode = 0, ResultData = "", ResultFlag = false, ResultValue = $"Bağlantı kesildi. Sistem Mesajı: \r\n{ex.Message}" };
                ////    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return nullResult;


                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Model.Result nullResult = new Model.Result { ResultCode = 0, ResultData = "", ResultFlag = false, ResultValue = $"Bağlantı kesildi. Sistem Mesajı: \r\n{ex.Message}" };
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return nullResult;

            throw;
        }
    }


There is a simple example:
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("localhost:8080");

string jsonData = @"{""username"" : ""myusername"", ""password"" : ""mypassword""}"

var content = new StringContent (jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/foo/login", content);

// this result string should be something like: "{"token":"rgh2ghgdsfds"}"
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Note:
Where /foo/login will need to point to your HTTP resource. For example, if you have an AccountController with a Login method, then instead of /foo/login you would use something like /Account/Login.

It says "cannot access a closed stream". I set my urls like you said. Where could it be wrong ?

Could you please post the latest code? And which line of code reports such a problem?

I add my post method. @Jessie Zhang -MSFT

It works like normal, send object to server but it gives me error like "cannot access a closed stream". Probably when I check it sends object but dont return me any error or message yet but next time when I try send my object it gives me error because connection closed as I understand. Do I understand how it works?

Which line of code reports such a problem?

var postData = await client.PostAsync(adres, content).ConfigureAwait(false); This line cause error it says " cannot access a closed stream" But I can see on logs it sends MIKRO object to server. Its weird. @Jessie Zhang -MSFT

If it is convenient for you, could you please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example here?

I fixed the problem with a different way. My friend write a code to check api health. First, I check api health and then if the result was OK I make the post. Thank you for your effort.

Congrats. You can post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)
